# Подсчет и сортировка количества букв в тексте

Tags: python, zip, count

Требуется подсчитать количество букв, результат отсортировать по частоте встречаемости букв (по возрастанию или убыванию). Регистр символов имеет значение.

Во кусок кода, а дальше ступор... Распаковка архива, чтение файла и почти сортировка букв (нужно дернуть только буквы RU и EN алфавита и отсортировать их с подсчетом)

```
import zipfile
from collections import Counter

archive = zipfile.ZipFile('voyna-i-mir.zip', 'r')
archive.extractall()
archive.close()

fin = open('voyna-i-mir.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')
data = fin.read().replace(' ', '')

counts = Counter(data)
for i in counts:
    print(i, counts[i])
```

Comment: Буквы наверное лучше регуляркой искать по текстам и сразу скармливать в Counter найденное.

Comment: можно регуляркой выбрать только буквы по типу - \w+ - без символов(типа !";%:?*()), без чисел, без пробелов только буквы. И уже считать дальше :) https://www.regexpal.com/ поиграйтесь

Comment: ```sorted_book = (re.search(r'[а-я-А-Я-a-z-A-Z]\w+'))        
print(sorted_book)```  ругается ```1 required positional argument: 'string'```

Answer (score 0):

```
from string import ascii_letters

ru_symbols = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'
ru_symbols += ru_symbols.upper()

symbols = []
for i in counts:
    if i in ru_symbols or i in ascii_letters:
        symbols.append((count[i], i))

symbols.sort(reverse=True)
```

Comment: Не обязательно все буквы перечислять, достаточно проверки `if i.isalpha():`

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: и мне нужно буквы двух языков и регистр тоже учитывается для подсчёта

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import zipfile
from collections import Counter

archive = zipfile.ZipFile('voyna-i-mir.zip', 'r')
archive.extractall()
archive.close()

pattern = r'[А-Яа-яA-Za-z]'

with open('voyna-i-mir.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as book:
    book_txt = book.read()

letters = re.findall(pattern, book_txt, flags=re.MULTILINE)

counts = Counter(letters)
for i in counts:
    print(i, counts[i])
```

Подправил, как теперь отсортировать вывод по возрастанию или убыванию ?

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `book.read()` нужно в `re.findall` отдавать - файл же нужно прочитать

Comment: можете всю строку написать как должна выглядеть ?

Comment: ```with open('voyna-i-mir.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as book:
    book_txt = book.read()``` догнал...